# React Native CLI Obfuscate the code or minify?

Tags: react-native

Does React Native CLI obfuscate the code or does it minify it?

From the [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/commands.md)

--minify [boolean]

Allows overriding whether bundle is minified. This defaults to false if dev is true, and true if dev is false. Disabling minification can be useful for speeding up production builds for testing purposes.